# solr spellcheck not returning any suggestions

Tags: solr

My spellcheck originally was working fine and then recently i noticed somewhere in past few months it stopped working. Spend huge amount of time to find what went wrong but no clue. Any help is much appreciated.

Below are my handler config

```
<str name="spellcheck">true</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
       <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
```

Below are my spellcheck component config

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.FileBasedSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="sourceLocation">mesh1.txt</str> 
      <str name="characterEncoding">UTF-8</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellcheckerFile</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.build">true</str>
```

I am able to see spellcheck is turned on in the solr query result. But it is not returning any suggestions

```
"spellcheck":{
      "suggestions":[]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was dictionary file did not got built. Because to build a file apart from adding "spellcheck.build> true" in config file, we also have to pass a url with command &spellcheck.build=true
This has to be done only once.